# Is Google's FileDataStore supported in UWP?

Tags: c#, youtube-api, uwp, google-api-dotnet-client, youtube-data-api

I'm using the Youtube api v3 and require the FileDataStore (Google.Apis.Util.Store.FileDataStore). I have all the necessary using directives and NuGet packages but I'm still getting a "The type or namespace name 'FileDataStore' could not be found" error.

The same code works in both Winforms and WPF. Is FileDataStore not supported in UWP? Is there a workaround?

```
  UserCredential credential;
            using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for full read/write access to the
                    // authenticated user's account.
                    new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube },
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(this.GetType().ToString())
                );
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Google .Net client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client) does not currently support UWP.

We were hoping to support UWP in the v2 release, but have had some issues with that. See [#787](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/787) for v2 details.

We have no specific timescale for working on native/UWP support (including [#838](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/838)). It'll be a matter of weeks/months.

Comment: Thanks. I'm quite surprised UWP is not supported yet.

Comment: we are having issues with backwards compatibility between two different libraries.     Its on the list of things to do but we have no time frame of when it will be supported.